# How do I properly create prototype objects from another file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running into a really frustrating problem in Node.js.

I'll start with what I'm doing.

I'm creating an object in a file and then exporting the constructor and creating it in other files.

My objects are defined like so:

**File 1:**

```
var Parent = function() {};

Parent.prototype = {
     C: function () { ... }
}

module.exports = Parent;
```

**File 2:**

```
var Parent = require('foo.js'),
      util = require('util'),
      Obj = function(){ this.bar = 'bar' };
util.inherits(Obj, Parent);
Obj.prototype.A = function(){ ... };
Obj.prototype.B = function(){ ... };
module.exports = Obj;
```

I'm trying to use the object like so in another file

**File 3:**

```
var Obj = require('../obj.js'),
      obj = new Obj();

obj.A();
```

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'A'
```

however when I run Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) I get:

```
{ A: [Function], B: [Function] }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `util.inherits` do? Does your code work if you omit the `Parent` thing (since `A` is a `Obj`-method)?

Comment: It's a Node.Js utility function [API Doc](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor)

Comment: I'm not able to help you, i will come back if I find a solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that, in addition to my answer, if I copy and paste your source code, above (and fix the path issues and replace the `...`s), I can run it with no issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is my setup:

**parent.js**

```
var Parent = function() {};

Parent.prototype = {
  C: function() {
    console.log('Parent#C');
  }
};

module.exports = Parent;
```

**child.js**

```
var Parent = require('./parent'),
    util = require('util');

var Child = function() {
  this.child = 'child';
};

util.inherits(Child, Parent);

Child.prototype.A = function() {
  console.log('Child#A');
};

module.exports = Child;
```

**main.js**

```
var Child = require('./child');
child = new Child();

child.A();
child.C();
```

And running `main.js`:

```
$ node main.js
Child#A
Parent#C
```

The source code is clonable via Git at the following Gist: https://gist.github.com/4704412

---

Aside: to clarify the `exports` vs `module.exports` discussion:

If you want to *attach new properties* to the exports object, you can use `exports`. If you want to *completely reassign exports to a new value*, you muse use `module.exports`. For example:

```
// correct
exports.myFunc = function() { ... };
// also correct
module.exports.myFunc = function() { ... };

// not correct
exports = function() { ... };
// correct
module.exports = function() { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks for the info I'm afraid there might be something else wrong that I'm doing. I'll check out your example on my setup.

Comment: Okay I must be doing something else wrong since your code works fine in my environment.

Comment: what method do you use for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @CalvinR I don't understand. What are you trying to do? I replicated your code in my answer, and it works. There must be a problem elsewhere. If you can explain your issue, I'd be happy to try to help.

Comment: I'm trying to create an object that inherits from another object, expose it and then call it from another file. 

My problem is that for some reason my created objects don't seem to be able to access their prototype chain. 

My actual code is very similar to what I have here but I'm obviously doing something wrong and it's not working.

If you want to take a look my project is here: https://github.com/CalvinRodo/WedXpress

Specifically I'm having a problem with the code in DataLayer and RegistryAdmin

Comment: @CalvinR Nothing stands out to me right off the bat as being wrong; why don't you drop me an email with some additional details and we'll see what we can figure out. You can get to my contact info from my SO profile.

Comment: turns out I know what I'm doing, I just don't know how to spell my problem was a case mismatch in what I was calling my function and how I was calling it, get vs Get :(